# git in a local repository: get file of older version without changing repository

Tags: git

I'm working in a local repository. I do not want to change anything in the repository, just retrieve an older version

Once I located the hash of a previous checkpoint, how can I get the file, how it was back then?

Do I have to clone, branch and delete after I got it?

Comment: git stash your local repository to retrieve them later if needed, then git branch to retrieve the branch you want, is the answer you're looking for similar to this?

Comment: @YousefAl-Hadhrami: no, that would change something in the repository.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve an older version of a file without changing anything in your repository by giving a commit hash and file name to `git show`:

```
git show <hash>:<file>
```

For example

```
git show 842c6dcc:scp/scp.c
```